# Who put the bounty on Fennec Shand?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-mandalorian

In *The Mandalorian* episode 1.05 (Chapter 5, The Gunslinger), Din Djarin goes to look for bounty guild work in Mos Eisley on the planet Tatooine, to pay for repairs he needs for his ship.

At a local cantina, Din learns that the guild no longer operates on Tatooine, but meets a wanna-be bounty hunter named Toro Calican, who collected a bounty of deadly assassin named [Fennac Shand](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Fennec_Shand) before he left Mid Rim. Toro wants Din Djarin to help him so he can officially join the bounty guild. Knowing of her reputation, Din goes on to explain that she will be hard to catch being such a well-known mercenary and since The New Republic had shut down many of her former crime-syndicate employers...

My question is, *Whose the client that put the bounty on Fennec Shand?*

###### Note: Perhaps this has not been answered yet, but could very soon be with the launch of spin-off series, *The Book of Boba Fett*.

Answer (score 2):

Fennec was wanted by the [ISB](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Imperial_Security_Bureau) (Imperial Security Bureau). It's not directly confirmed whether this is what lead to her having a bounty puck, but it seems a fair bet as the ISB are known to use the Guild to track down people that they want.

> “Because these remnant bases are set up and run by ex-ISB,” Mayfeld
> informed her. “If you get scanned and your genetic signature shows up
> on any New Republic register you’re gonna be detected, and it’s guns
> out.”
>
> Cara glared at him. “You sure do know a lot about Imperial remnants.”
>
> “Hey, if you want to accuse me of something,” Mayfeld snapped, “then
> just say it.”
>
> “We don’t have time for this,” Mando said. “Fennec will go.”
>
> “I’m wanted by the ISB,” Fennec said. “I’ll trip the alarm, too.”
>
> <sub><sup>[The Mandalorian: Season 2 - Junior Novelisation](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Mandalorian_Season_2_Junior_Novel)</sup></sub>